# How to fix "Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)"

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I am trying to add a meta tag to my page when the server renders. But I got this error:

```js
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.       
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4053:17)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at Object.renderToString (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\server\/server.js:16:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
```

Đây là `server.js`:

```js
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import React from 'react';
import express from 'express';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = 3006;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
            <App />
        </StaticRouter>,
    );

    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');
    fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
        }
        res.send(formatHTML(app, helmet));
    });
});
const formatHTML = (appStr, helmet) => {
    return `
 <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}
        ${helmet.link.toString()}
    </head>
    <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()}>
        <div id="app">
            ${appStr}                
        </div>
    </body>       
</html>
`;
};
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Everything works fine at home page until I switch to another page eg: `http://localhost:3006/news`.

This is what the server returns:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it&#39;s defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4053:17)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.renderToString (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\server\/server.js:15:29<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at param (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (E:\WorkSpace\MyProject\font_end_vnsupplements\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe the page/component corresponding to `/news` is not present or exported. What exactly is it expected to render when `/news` is pinged?

Comment: That's the page where I use react-helmet to change the page title.